# Override jquery onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a button in ASP.NET, that renders to HTML as such:

```
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="clickme">
```

If I then add the jquery:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){return false;});
```

Every time the button is clicked, nothing will happen (i.e. no postback).
This is fine.

Is there any way in Javascript I can programatically invoke the click (which will cause a postback) whilst also disregarding the jquery-attached, `return false` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the event handler accept additional arguments. When triggering the handler with [`.trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) you can specify values for these arguments, which will let the handler modify its behavior accordingly.

For example:

```
$("#btn").click(function(event, submitForm) {
    submitForm = submitForm || false;
    if (!submitForm) return false;
});

// This will not submit the form
$("#btn").trigger("click");

// But this will
$("#btn").trigger("click", true);
```

Comment: FYI this line can be removed: `submitForm = submitForm || false;`

Comment: @David: I know, it's just a habit of making sure parameters have known values "of the correct type".

Answer (score 1):

The button itself does nothing by default except submitting the form, so try this:

```
$('#btn').closest('form').submit();
```

Comment: 'Normally' yes, but not in ASP.NET

Comment: @maxp Based on the code you posted, my example should submit the form programmatically just as it would when you click a submit button. If the postback is called using some other logic, you should post more code in the question.

Comment: I specifically said the page was rendered in ASP.NET. The code you posted above demonstrates a lack of knowledge and understanding of how the framework and the client/server relationship works.

Comment: No "page" is rendered in ASP.NET, it is rendered in HTML. And since you posted HTML, I assumed that this was the code you had questions about. Sorry if I misunderstood your question based on that assumption.

Comment: Sorry, 'ASP.NET rendered the HTML' would've made more sense.